# Javascript -= command multiplying every loop

Tags: javascript, html

I am a new programmer, making my first non-tutorial game, and I am having a problem with the enemy in-game. Heres the script:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Square</title>
    <style>
            * { padding: 0; margin: 0; }
            canvas { background: #000; display: block; margin: 0 auto; }
        </style>
</head>
<body bgcolor="#000111">

<canvas id="myCanvas" width="480" height="320"></canvas>

<div id="nocursor"><!-- some stuff --></div>

<form name="Show">
<input type="text" name="MouseX" value="0" size="4"> X<br>
<input type="text" name="MouseY" value="0" size="4"> Y<br>
</form>

<script language="JavaScript1.2">

    document.getElementById('nocursor').style.cursor = 'none';

    var canvas=document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

    var x=canvas.width/2;
    var y=canvas.height-30;
    var playerHeight = 100;
    var playerWidth = 20;
    var enemyHeight = 10;
    var enemyWidth = 10;
    var IE = document.all?true:false
    var enemyXPos = 470;
    var rand = Math.random();
    var left = 0;
    var right = 0;
    var up = 0;
    var down = 0;
    var lefta = 0;
    var rightd = 0;
    var upw = 0;
    var downs = 0;
    var space = false;
    var playerColor="#ffffff";
    var score = 0;


function click() {
document.addEventListener("click", startEnemy);
}

//Check for keydown arrows
document.onkeydown = function(event) {
     if (!event)
          event = window.event;
     var code = event.keyCode;
     if (event.charCode && code == 0)
          code = event.charCode;
     switch(code) {
          case 37:
        left-=20;
              break;
          case 38:
        up+=20;
              break;
          case 39:
        right+=20;
              break;
          case 40:
        down-=20;
              break;
      case 65:
        lefta-=10;
              break;
          case 87:
        upw+=10;
              break;
          case 68:
        rightd+=10;
              break;
          case 83:
        downs-=10;
              break;
      case 32:
        space=true;
              break;

     }
     event.preventDefault();
};
document.onkeydown = function(event) {
     if (!event)
          event = window.event;
     var code = event.keyCode;
     if (event.charCode && code == 0)
          code = event.charCode;
     switch(code) {
          case 37:
        left+=20;
              break;
          case 38:
        up+=20;
              break;
          case 39:
        right+=20;
              break;
          case 40:
        down+=20;
              break;
      case 65:
        lefta+=10;
              break;
          case 87:
        upw+=10;
              break;
          case 68:
        rightd+=10;
              break;
          case 83:
        downs+=10;
              break;
     }
     event.preventDefault();
};

if (!IE) document.captureEvents(Event.MOUSEMOVE)


document.onmousemove = getMouseXY;


var tempX = 0
var tempY = 0

// Main function to retrieve mouse x-y pos.s

function getMouseXY(e) {
  if (IE) {
    tempX = event.clientX + document.body.scrollLeft
    tempY = event.clientY + document.body.scrollTop
  } else {
    tempX = e.pageX
    tempY = e.pageY
  }  

  if (tempX < 0){tempX = 0}
  if (tempY < 0){tempY = 0}  

  document.Show.MouseX.value = tempX
  document.Show.MouseY.value = tempY
  return true
}

function drawScore() {
    ctx.font = "16px Arial";
    ctx.fillStyle = "#0095DD";
    ctx.fillText("Score: "+score, 410, 20);
}

function collision() {
    if (enemyXPos<=20 && downs-upw >= down-up && downs-upw <= down-up+playerHeight && enemyXPos >= 0) {
        playerColor="#FF0000";
        setTimeout(gameOver, 100);
    }
}

function gameOver() {
    console.log("COLLISION");
    alert("GAME OVER, YOUR SCORE WAS: "  + score + "!");
    document.location.reload();
}

function checkSpace() {
    if (space=true) {
        startEnemy();
        space=false;
    }
}

function drawPlayer() {

    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.rect(0, down-up, playerWidth, playerHeight);    
    ctx.fillStyle=playerColor;
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.closePath();

}

function drawEnemy() {

    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.rect(enemyXPos-=1, downs-upw, enemyWidth, enemyHeight);
    ctx.fillStyle="#ffffff";
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.closePath();

    if (enemyXPos<0) {
        startEnemy();
    }


}

function placePlayer() {
    drawPlayer();
    requestAnimationFrame(placePlayer);
}
function startEnemy() {
    console.log("enemy shot");
    enemyXPos = 470;
    placeEnemy();
    score+=1;
}
function placeEnemy() {
    drawEnemy();
    collision();
    drawScore();
    requestAnimationFrame(placeEnemy);
}

function draw() {
click();
placePlayer();
}
draw();


</script>
</body>
</html>
```

On the line that moves the enemy,  every time the enemy respawns, it's speed gets faster, and I don't want it to. The problem is in the drawEnemy function:

```
function drawEnemy() {

    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.rect(enemyXPos-=1, downs-upw, enemyWidth, enemyHeight);
    ctx.fillStyle="#ffffff";
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.closePath();

    if (enemyXPos<0) {
        startEnemy();
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your function `placeEnemy` forms an infinite loop, calling itself (via `requestAnimationFrame`) every time it executes.

`startEnemy` calls `placeEnemy` every time it executes. This means that each "re-spawn" starts a new infinite loop, **without cancelling the old one**.

The `placeEnemy` loop modifies the "enemy" position (`enemyXPos`) by subtracting `1` each iteration. With multiple loops running simultaneously, `1` is subtracted multiple times each time a new "animation frame" is fired.

You can fix this by not calling `placeEnemy` in `startEnemy`: just reset the enemy's position, and let the same animation loop continue!

Comment: Glad this solves the issue. If this is the correct solution, you should mark it as such.

Comment: Generally speaking, you should have only one animation loop running in your application. To add more control, you can place the recursive call inside a conditional, e.g. `if (running) { requestAnimationFrame(placeEnemy); }` That way, you can pause the animation by setting `running` to `false`, and you can check that `running` is `false` before re-starting the animation. There also exists a function `cancelAnimationFrame`, which can be used for even more precise control. You can see a basic example [here](https://css-tricks.com/using-requestanimationframe/#article-header-id-2).

Comment: My level isnt 15 yet, sorry so i cant make a publicly displayed vote D: